# How to assign const value to bit-fields while it is within the typedef?

Tags: c, typedef, unions, bit-fields

I don't have any ideas.

```
typedef union {
    struct {
        uint8_t start_bit : 1; // always is 0
        uint8_t transmission_bit : 1; // always is 1
        uint8_t cmd : 6;
        uint32_t arg;
        uint8_t crc : 7;
        uint8_t end_bit :1; // always is 1
    } bit;
    uint8_t reg[6];
} Command_t;
```

I need some of bits always equals 1 or 0.

Comment: `Command_t c; c.bit.start_bit = 0; c.bit.transmission_bit = 1;` etc.?

Comment: You can't specify that some fields should always have a particular value when you create a type (synonym) with a `typedef`. Either do what zenith suggested or initialize each object with e.g. `Command_t c = { { .start_bit = 0, .transmission_bit = 1 } }`.

Comment: Ok! Thank you. Will use full initialisation every time I need this type.

Comment: I think to use something like constructor.

Comment: then you should leave the pure C world :)